# filter wptexturize doesn't work on old posts titles

Tags: filters, mysql, encoding

> I have an `add_filter('the_content', 'wpt_content');`. My function
>   `wpt_content` does a `wptexturize($text)`. But It's work only on save
>   post, so my old post has bad `'`and my new post `’`.
>
> I don't know how to save all posts in few steps or how to apply filter
>   on all existing post.

I was wrong, this is a problem on XML export import process, `post_title` are not saved with a `'`but with a `&#039;`, I fix this with a sql :

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = REPLACE (
post_title,
'&#039;',
'\'');
```

Comment: I was wrong, this a problem with `&#039;`…

Comment: `the_content` runs on post display. It should work for any post and has nothing to do with `save_post` (nor does anything get saved to the database). Something about this question is missing. You need to provide more information and more code.

Comment: I have to check my XML import from the old wp and mysql database, there is something wrong on my title.